# What is the best way to bind a periodic action to the Mono lifecycle?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to perform an action every second while the Mono is active. What is the best way to do this?

Here is a working option, but it seems like a workaround:

```java
// Some long life async action
Mono<String> asyncAction = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).map(d -> "Hello");

Mono<String> periodicAction = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .doOnNext(d -> {
            // Do something every second while the async action is running
        })
        .last()
        .flatMap(d -> Mono.never());

Mono.firstWithSignal(asyncAction, periodicAction)
        // Another logic
        .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using method `zip` for example:

```
static <T1,T2> Flux<Tuple2<T1,T2>>  zip(Publisher<? extends T1> source1, Publisher<? extends T2> source2)
```

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#zip-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-

Example:

```
        Flux.zip(
                Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).doOnNext(System.out::println).log(),
                Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).map(d -> "Hello").log()
        )
                .map(Tuple2::getT2)
                .log()
                .as(StepVerifier::create)
                .expectNextCount(1)
                .verifyComplete()
```

In `zip` method java docs we can read that:

> Zip two sources together, that is to say wait for all the sources to emit one element and combine these elements once into a {@link Tuple2}. The operator will continue doing so until any of the sources completes.

Comment: Perhaps I poorly described the question, but how can this operator help me? I don't want to get the second result, I just want to do some extra work while I wait for the result of the async operation.

Comment: @abler98 I edited my response and added example.